# Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't bring up unlock dialog when turning monitor back on or switching on KVM

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, lock-screen

HP EliteDesk 800 Mini-PC G3 (35W) and Lenovo ThinkCentre M900, Ubuntu 22.04.2, fresh install.

If I have locking enabled:

When switching back to the computer on a KVM I get a blank screen, but it seems to be waking the display because the screen brightens slightly after a second or two. If the monitor was off it comes back to a blank screen. Keyboard and mouse activity doesn't bring up an unlock/login dialog.

Both of these thin PCs have two displayport ports, but it doesn't seem to matter which one I plug into.

I have masked all the suspend/hibernate modes. I can ssh in to the boxes, I can start a ping and it's completely uninterrupted.

Disabling screen locking is a workaround, but I would rather not leave the display unlocked.

It almost seems like its trying to display the unlock dialog but on the "other" screen, but it doesn't seem to matter which port I use.

Perhaps there's an option to display the unlock dialog on all screens?